# Zoo Visitor not sending forgot password email

Tags: zoo-visitor

I have a basic zoo visitor forgot password form and the email's aren't being sent out.

```
        {exp:zoo_visitor:forgot_password error_handling="inline"}
        {if password_sent}
            <h3>A password reset email has been sent to the provided email.</h3>
        {if:else}
            <fieldset>
            <p>
                <label for="email" class="form-label">Your email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-text" value="" />
                <input type="submit" value="Retrieve password" class="button" />
            </p>
            {error:email}
            </fieldset>
        {/if}
    {/exp:zoo_visitor:forgot_password}
```

Emails are being sent from the member registration form so i've ruled out server issues. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that all the emails are getting blocked by the ISP spam. Emails sent with PHP are very unreliable in the long run, and why services like SendGrid and Mandrill are so useful. One recommendation would be to try to send your emails using a proper service. SendGrid and Mandrill both have free accounts, and you get like 12,000 emails a month (so it's free for most of our clients).

I helped Christopher track the issues down before, but I can't 100% remember what he concluded. Postmaster is always a viable option to sending forgot password forms with SendGrid or Mandrill, but it's possible to use SMTP and do it without Postmaster.

Comment: Yea, it seems like emails are a huge black box. Especially with this site because the client has an IT team so we passed over an IP address for them to use as an A record. We had some success with emails with a plain old PHP mail() script, but it only worked sometimes with certain email addresses. I will give SendGrid and Mandrill a try. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You can also test the default email sending functionality here: Tools > Communicate. If that works consistently, you'll know it's an issue with Zoo Visitor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without your conditional statement?

Comment: Just reloads the page and emails still don't send.

Comment: seems Christopher had the same issue back in Sept http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/7112#23995

Comment: yep, I saw that too. They don't resolve the issue in the thread, unfortunately.

Comment: Steven, if you have a question or need more information, please post that as a comment on the original question, rather than posting it as a new answer.